# Nested SQL command in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sqlcommand, crystal-reports-xi

Is it possible to use the result from a command on another command in Crystal Reports?

As an example, I have a command

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo2 IN (list)
```

saved as command_1
Now I want

```
SELECT xfoo FROM xbar WHERE xfoo2 IN (command_1.foo)
```

In a simple case I realise I could just combine them to

```
SELECT xfoo FROM xbar WHERE xfoo2 IN (SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo2 IN (list))
```

but in my real world case that gives me errors due to too many nested SELECTs.

My real world example if someone wants to give a specific and not just a general answer:

Existing command saved as `pnr`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rem.pop_pid
FROM a_remiss rem
INNER JOIN a_bestall best ON rem.arem_id = best.arem_id
JOIN a_prov prov ON best.apro_id = prov.apro_id
WHERE prov.pro_provdat >= {ts '2006-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND prov.pro_provdat <= {ts '2011-12-31 23:59:59'}
AND best.ana_analyskod IN ('PKREAT', 'PKREA', 'PKREAN')
AND (
rem.pop_pid LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] 1[89]'
OR rem.pop_pid LIKE '[01][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] 20'
)
```

Wanted additional new command:

```
SELECT arem_id, apro_id, ana_analyskod
FROM a_bestall
WHERE ana_analyskod IN('ABSBIK', 'BCRPS')
AND arem_id IN (
SELECT arem_id
FROM a_remiss
WHERE rem_ank_dttm >= {ts '2006-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND rem_ank_dttm <= {ts '2012-01-31 23:59:59'}
AND pop_pid IN pnr.pop_pid
)
```

*EDIT: Fixed a code error that now makes the nested SELECTs work, but it would still be nice to be able to nest commands.*

Comment: Only second question on SO and well formed from the beginning. Great!

Comment: You can create two separate commands, then join them on the client side. Very inefficient, but if the data set is not big, it can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, Commands can not be nested.

If you can get the syntax to work in a query tool, it should work in a Command.

If you are still getting syntax errors, consider using a different database driver.  I've noticed that the 'native' drivers do a better job than ODBC.